taskhostw.exe
windows 8
антивирус не даёт установить, если установил, то не помогают. Единственный способ вручную - зайти в его папку и удалить exe. Естественно папку закрывает. Какие ещё есть способы вручную?
Realtek HD Audio taskhostw.exe
hitman и antimalware только убрали, каждые две минуты всплывающее окно, ошибки с этим вирусом

Возможный дубликат вопроса: taskhostw.exe windows 8
